# How do I change the user Transmission runs under?

Tags: services, upstart, transmission

I installed Transmission through a PPA and the daemon starts on boot. I want to change the user that runs the daemon because I want the downloaded files to be under the same user as my XBMC installation, and I can't seem to find where to edit that.

The daemon uses upstart so there is nothing about which users runs it in `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` and there isn't anything in `/etc/default/transmission-daemon` about the user either

I'm using these ppas for transmission:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/transmissionbt-ppa-quantal.list:deb //ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu quantal main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/transmissionbt-ppa-quantal.list:deb-src //ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu quantal main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/transmissionbt-ppa-quantal.list.save:deb //ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu quantal main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/transmissionbt-ppa-quantal.list.save:deb-src //ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
```

Comment: Can you please provide the PPA and the version of Ubuntu? Everywhere I looked the transmission-daemon package does have the /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon file.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant that there isn't anything about which user runs the daemon in that file

Comment: At the start of the /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon file you should see the line "USER=debian-transmission"; that should be it.

Comment: Mine looks like this: https://gist.github.com/boukevanderbijl/04c7d6a322a08e9629cb

Comment: I added which PPAs I use in the starting post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of upstart v1.4, [`setuid`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) and [`setgid`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setgid) are supported natively in config file:

```
setgid <groupname>
```

and

```
setuid <username>
```

Before v1.4 you can use this ([as described here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user)):

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start -c {user} --exec {command}
```

Comment: I have to edit /etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf

Comment: I had also to   

    sudo chown -R user:group /var/lib/transmission-daemon/

like said http://askubuntu.com/questions/290943/transmission-daemon-error-loading-working-config-file-user-priveliges

Answer (score 18):

Since all of the other answers are for Ubuntu pre-systemd, here's an updated guide for Ubuntu 16.04 ([from sensecodons.com](http://blog.sensecodons.com/2017/01/running-transmission-as-user-in-ubuntu.html)).  Essentially, create a supplementary unit for "transmission-daemon.service" to change the `User=...` setting and then update that user's "~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json" file.

> Stop transmission (if it's already running).
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl stop transmission-daemon
> ```
>
> Create the supplement file directory for transmission:
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d
> ```
>
> Create a new supplement file called "run-as-user.conf".
>
> ```
> sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/run-as-user.conf
> ```
>
> and put the following text in it.
>
> ```
> [Service]
> User=codon
> ```
>
> Obviously, use your desired username and not "codon".
>
> Tell systemd to reload its units.
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
> ```

Next, you'll want to start and then stop transmission to make it create the `~/.config/transmission-daemon/` directory for your new user.

> Start transmission and then stop transmission.
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl start transmission-daemon; sudo systemctl stop transmission-daemon
> ```
>
> You should now have the following directory in your user's home directory:
>   `.config/transmission-daemon/`

From here, you should be able to update `~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json` normally.

When you're done, start transmission.

```
sudo systemctl start transmission-daemon
```

Comment: Instead of manually creating that directory and file, use `systemctl edit transmission-daemon.service`, which will automatically 1. create that directory and file, and 2. when you save and exit, run `systemctl daemon-reload` as well.

Comment: Thanks. Working on raspbian

Answer (score 12):

### Assumptions:

- You used this PPA: `ppa:transmissionbt/ppa`
- You want to run Transmission with user: `some_user` and group: `some_group`

### For System V (SysV) init system (eg: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS):

1. Stop the Transmission Daemon:

   ```
   sudo service transmission-daemon stop
   ```
2. Edit the init.d scripts

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
   ```

   ...and change `USER=debian-transmission` to `USER=some_user`

### For Upstart init system (eg: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):

1. Stop the Transmission Daemon:

   ```
   sudo service transmission-daemon stop
   ```
2. Edit the init scripts:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf
   ```

   ...and edit as follows:

   - change `setuid debian-transmission` to `setuid some_user`
   - and change `setgid debian-transmission` to `setgid some_group`

### For systemd init system (eg: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS):

1. Stop the Transmission Daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop transmission-daemon.service
   ```
2. Create systemd override.conf file:

   ```
   sudo systemctl edit transmission-daemon.service
   ```

   ...and edit as follows:

   ```
   [Service]
   User=
   User=some_user
   Group=
   Group=some_group
   ```

   *Notes:*

   - *This creates the following file: `/etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/override.conf`*
   - *The empty variable assignments (eg: `User=`) are used to clear/reset the value in the existing variable. This seems to be how things are done when using drop-in replacement of the systemd unit file. See: "Example 2. Overriding vendor settings" in [systemd.unit manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Examples):*

     > "...for drop-in files, if one wants to remove entries from a setting that is parsed as a list (and is not a dependency), ... one needs to first clear the list before re-adding all entries except the one that is to be removed..."
3. Systemd reload and start transmission daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl start transmission-daemon.service
   ```

   *Note: Unlike with Upstart and SysV init systems transmission-daemon saves all configuration and settings in `/home/some_user/.config/transmission-daemon/` instead of `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` and `/var/lib/transmission-daemon`*

### Notes & References

- `/etc/default/transmission-daemon` is used only by the Upstart scripts (`/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`) and SysV scripts (`/etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf`) and so if you are using Systemd init system then you can ignore all these files.
- [Running transmission as a user in Ubuntu 16.04](http://blog.sensecodons.com/search/label/transmission)
- [Reddit: Changing systemd user with drop-in replacement for transmission-daemon not working](https://www.reddit.com/r/systemd/comments/5a5iog/changing_systemd_user_with_dropin_replacement_for/)
- [Stack-Exchange: Changing systemd user with drop-in replacement for transmission-daemon not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318342/changing-systemd-user-with-drop-in-replacement-for-transmission-daemon-not-worki)

---

### Optional/Additional Information regarding permissions and package updates:

> *Note: The following is likely only relevant for Upstart and SysV init systems only*

**Changing Permissions on Transmission's configuration files**

If you are not using systemd init system you may now need to change the permissions for Transmission's Configuration files from `user=debian-transmission` to `user=some_user` and from `group=debian-transmission` to `group=some_group`.

1. Check the location of your Transmission Configuration Directory. You can find it mentioned in the `/etc/default/transmission-daemon` file as a line like so:

   ```
   CONFIG_DIR="/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info"
   ```
2. So assuming your Configuration Directory is `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info`, change ownership of configuration files:

   ```
   sudo chown some_user:some_group /var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads
   sudo chown some_user:some_group /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
   sudo chown some_user:some_group /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/blocklists
   sudo chown some_user:some_group /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/dht.dat
   sudo chown some_user:some_group /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/resume
   sudo chown some_user:some_group /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/torrents
   ```
3. Change ownership of other files:

   ```
   sudo chown :some_group /etc/transmission-daemon
   sudo chown some_user:some_group /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
   ```

**Extra Information (updating Transmission):**

Because you changed the default user you may find that after updating Transmission using the repository (eg: apt-get upgrade) the transmission daemon is no longer running.

Running "sudo apt-get -f install" give the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up transmission-daemon (2.84-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
 * Starting bittorrent daemon transmission-daemon
invoke-rc.d: initscript transmission-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing transmission-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 transmission-daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The reason the daemon fails to start ("invoke-rc.d: initscript transmission-daemon, action "start" failed.") is because we changed permissions from "debian-transmission" to "some_user" and after the update these got reset. So to fix just do the following:

1. Stop Daemon and Edit config file:

   ```
   sudo service transmission-daemon stop
   sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
   ```

   ...and change `USER=some_user` to `USER=debian-transmission`
2. Re-try fixing update by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
3. If the update succeeds the Transmission daemon should now be running. You can now follow steps above to change user/group again.

Comment: Fantastic answer, but do you know to change the *group* on SysV? I see `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` contains `USER=` but no `GROUP=`.

Comment: Hard for me to test this right now but you could try editing `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` as follows. Add another variable `GROUP=some_group` in addition to the already existing variable `USER=some_user` and then change `--chuid $USER` to `--chuid $USER:$GROUP`. Also check the [start-stop-daemon man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html)

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and it looks like it's running as *both* groups now according to `grep '^Groups' /proc/$(pgrep transmission)/status`, but it's still creating new files as `debian-transmission:debian-transmission`.

Comment: I don't think it matters actually. I added my user to group `debian-transmission` instead and changed `settings.json`/`umask` to `2` so now I can move files around without a hitch.

Comment: This should be the top voted answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This is not the complete story. Apart from changing

```
setgid <groupname>
```

and

```
setuid <username>
```

in

```
/etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf
```

you also need to change the permissions of the config file of transmission-daemon. Otherwise it won't be able to rewrite settings to this file and the daemon will restart until upstart thinks it had enough chances (init: transmission-daemon respawning too fast, stopped)

```
sudo chown <user>:<group> /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> /var/lib/transmission-daemon/
```

Comment: Thanks for the bit about changing the permissions of `settings.json`. Missed that.

Answer (score 2):

On systems using systemd, the file you want to edit may actually be:

`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/transmission-daemon.service`

Follow up editing with:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: This is what helped me. I did all other steps but didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04 the startup service was changed from upstart to systemd, making must of the previous answers obsolete. To change the user transmission-daemon runs execute:

Stop daemon:

```
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
```

Change ownership of configuration files and "home":

```
sudo chown -R USER:USER /var/lib/transmission-daemon/*
sudo chown -R USER:USER /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Then edit file `/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service` with:

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=USER
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-debug --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please note the `User`, `--config-dir`and the `--log-debug` changes.

Reload systemd configuration:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start daemon again:

```
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

Once you have set the `--log-debug` (which will give you more information of any issue) option you can get the daemon's log:

```
sudo journalctl -u transmission-daemon.service
```

Done.

**Things to note:**

You can ignore files:

`/etc/default/transmission-daemon`: It seems that nobody is sourcing it in systemd systems.

`/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`: It seems that this was the old system 5 start script.

`/etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf`: It seems that this is the old upstart start script.

Comment: Do not edit `/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service` manually. Use `systemctl edit transmission-daemon.service` instead, or your changes will be lost when you upgrade the package.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following, which to me seems less invasive than the other answers.

1. Remove the startup of transmission-daemon:

   ```
   sudo update-rc.d -f transmission-daemon remove
   ```
2. Add the following to `/etc/profile`:

   ```
   if [ -f "$HOME/.autostart" ]; then
     $HOME/.autostart
   fi
   ```
3. Create `~/.autostart`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [ -z "$(pidof transmission-daemon)" ]; then
    /usr/bin/transmission-daemon --config-dir /home/[USERNAME]/.config/transmission-daemon &
   fi
   ```

This is a bit more portable perhaps, it works for me on plain Debian and minibian too.

Comment: not a bad idea but it requires that the user logins with a shell that executes `/etc/profile` (zsh doesn't execute it, for example)